# Simulate the toggle pin with MOSFET switch

Tags: mosfet, esp32, toggle-switch

I intend to use two devices (SD card, LCD) on a single ESP32 SPI line. To enable communication need to pull up chip select pin on each device, my question is, can simulate the toggle pin with MOSFET switch similar to the following schematic?
Default pin pulled up and always Enable LCD unless pin pulled down and enable the other device.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should work if:

- The SPI pins of both SD card and LCD are tri-state (high impedance if CS not selected).
- Both CS pins have the same polarity (if not, you would not even need the inverter)
- The MOSFET is a logic level type

Comment: @Justme is correct, drain and source are swapped.

Answer (score 2):

The FET is connected incorrectly. Just look at the diode symbol internal to the FET, it will always conduct and keep the SD CS high, with no way to set it low.

Comment: tnx for the comment, beside this drawing mistake , does this schematic work as a toggle switch ?

Comment: It depends how you are going to fix it, and whether you know the items mentioned in the answer by @MarcoZollinger will not be an issue. For example sending multiple commands to LCD means you need to delimit each command with CS so what does the SD card do when it receives CS pulses without transactions? It might work but I would not trust it as you don't say which LCD and back in the days SPI mode was somewhat problematic on SD/MMC cards, not all cards released the MISO out and thus were not able to share the bus.

Comment: @jusme , very interesting point, I use the RTOS for writing on SD card and LCD, and the rate of writing on SD is much higher than LCD, and that's the reason I put the SD card CS as default high, with this situation do you suggest to switch to multi CS pins of single toggle one